# Basic array function difficulties

Tags: c++

i'm having difficulty writing a basic function utilizing arrays. Essentially, this program inserts a number into an already sorted array. You are required to loop backwards over the array.

> i. Loop while your counter is greater than 0, and the value in the array at one
> position before your counter is greater than the value to insert.
> (That is, if you are at position 5, check if position 4 is greater than the value.)

> ii. Each time the loop runs, move the value from the position before your counter
> to the position of your counter.
> (That is, if you are at position 5, assign the value from position 4 to the array at
> position 5.)
> c. After the loop, put the value to insert into the array at the position of your counter.

This is what I have so far, and I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding something, as I feel like this *should* work, but it doesn't. I would appreciate any help. You simply return the new amount of values in the array at the end, which isn't hard -- but the actual insertion I am struggling with.

```
int main() {
//this is what i'm using to test the function
    double arrayOne[4];
    arrayOne[0] = 1;
    arrayOne[1] = 2;
    arrayOne[2] = 4;

    cout << insertValue(arrayOne, 3, 4, 3) << endl;
    cout << "0: " << arrayOne[0] << endl;
    cout << "1: " << arrayOne[1] << endl;
    cout << "2: " << arrayOne[2] << endl;
    cout << "3: " << arrayOne[3] << endl;

}
int insertValue(double array[], int numVals, int maxSize, double insertVal) {
//array[] - array we are inserting the number into
//numVals - number of values in the array
//maxSize - maximum size of the array
//insertVal - the value being inserted
    int newVal = numVals;
    int counter = numVals;
//this if is needed, unrelated to prompt
    if (numVals >= maxSize) {
        return maxSize;
    }
    for (int i = numVals; i > 0;  --i) {
        do 
        {
            array[counter] = array[counter - 1];
            --counter;
        } while ((counter > 0) && (array[counter - 1] > insertVal));
    }
    //for (int i = numVals;  (i > 0) && (array[i - 1] > insertVal); --i) {
    array[counter] = insertVal;  
    return newVal + 1;
}
```

Comment: It looks pretty close to what is required. However your for and do while loop seem to be doubling up and interfering with each other. I would replace with just a while loop.

Comment: You need to decrement `counter` in the loop

Comment: If it isn't too much trouble, could you demonstrate what a while loop would look like in this regard? Could I just "smash" the two statements together?

Comment: Draw up a flowchart that describes your code and you'll quickly see what the above posters are talking about.

Comment: *"I feel like this* should *work, but it doesn't."* -- What does it do? The best questions asking for debugging help include both the expected and actual results. It's even better if you can narrow down the problem to a specific line that is not behaving as you expect (a debugger is useful for this, as a debugger can show you the values of your variables as you step through your program).

Comment: Thank you for the help - I have resolved the error. Making a flowchart really assisted me in figuring the issue out, as my for loop was essentially running the same code in my do loop. We haven't covered debuggers extensively, but I will look into this for my next coding issue :). I will post the fixed code for posterity later